# Woocommerce custom script for discounts severely slowing site down

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm on the cusp of completing a website, and have been tweaking it for performance for the last week or so. Thus far, I've managed to bring my pagespeed score from an E to a solid B.

The problem is.... it's still takes forever and a day to load. More accurately it hangs for a long time while waiting for a site reply.

I believe I've narrowed it down to being an issue with a custom php script I've written that controls membership discounts. It overrides many Woocommerce functions like dynamically changing product/cart prices by membership level, and dynamically inserting product variation descriptions, and other product page information. It's pretty much integral to my shop operation, so I really need to find a way to minimize it's interference with site performance.

**EDIT** By request, I've posted a larger chunk of the script including the likely most problematic functions, and the slew a variable declarations at the top. Couldn't include the whole thing bc it doesn't fit in SO's character limit. I'm still pretty new to PHP so it isn't the cleanest and can probably be simplified.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$wp_user = wp_get_current_user();

//DECLARE MEMBERSHIP TYPE
$admin = in_array( 'administrator', (array) $wp_user->roles );
$free = in_array( 'free_member', (array) $wp_user->roles );
$bronze = in_array( 'bronze_member', (array) $wp_user->roles );
$silver = in_array( 'silver_member', (array) $wp_user->roles );
$gold = in_array( 'gold_member', (array) $wp_user->roles );
$platinum = in_array( 'platinum_member', (array) $wp_user->roles );
$doubleplatinum = in_array( 'double_platinum_member', (array) $wp_user->roles );
$diamond = in_array( 'diamond_member', (array) $wp_user->roles );
$freesync = in_array( 'free_sync_member', (array) $wp_user->roles );
$silversync = in_array( 'silver_sync_member', (array) $wp_user->roles );
$goldsync = in_array( 'gold_sync_member', (array) $wp_user->roles );

$nonpaid ='$free';


//SET VARIATION PRICES FOR EACH MEMBERSHIP TYPE
$pricedemo = 0;
$pricedemofree = .99;
$pricedemomp3bronze = $pricedemofree;
$pricedemomp3silver = 0;
$pricedemomp3gold = 0;
$pricedemomp3platinum = 0;
$pricedemomp3dblplatinum = 0;
$pricedemomp3diamond = 0;

$pricebasicmp3free =25;
$pricebasicmp3bronze =15;
$pricebasicmp3silver =15;
$pricebasicmp3gold =10;
$pricebasicmp3platinum = 10;
$pricebasicmp3dblplatinum =5;
$pricebasicmp3diamond = 1;

$pricebasicwavfree=35;
$pricebasicwavbronze =25;
$pricebasicwavsilver =25;
$pricebasicwavgold =10;
$pricebasicwavplatinum =10;
$pricebasicwavdblplatinum =5;
$pricebasicwavdiamond =1;

$pricepremiummp3free =85;
$pricepremiummp3bronze =70;
$pricepremiummp3silver =50;
$pricepremiummp3gold =40;
$pricepremiummp3platinum =30;
$pricepremiummp3dblplatinum =20;
$pricepremiummp3diamond = 10;

$pricepremiumwavfree =100;
$pricepremiumwavbronze =85;
$pricepremiumwavsilver =70;
$pricepremiumwavgold =40;
$pricepremiumwavplatinum =30;
$pricepremiumwavdblplatinum =20;
$pricepremiumwavdiamond =10;



$pricedemofreesync = .99;
$pricedemosilversync =0;
$pricedemogoldsync =0;

$pricesyncmp3freesync = 15;
$pricesyncmp3silversync =5;
$pricesyncmp3goldsync =1;

$pricesyncwavfreesync = 25;
$pricesyncwavsilversync =10;
$pricesyncwavgoldsync =5;


$demomp3 = '';
$basicmp3 = '';
$basicwav = '';
$premiummp3 = '';
$premiumwav = '';
$syncmp3 = '';
$syncwav = '';

$demomp3cart = '';
$basicmp3cart = '';
$basicwavcart = '';
$premiummp3cart = '';
$premiumwavcart = '';
$syncmp3cart = '';
$syncwavcart = '';

$getcat ='';
$category = '';
$categories = array();

$showmessage= false;


//OVERRIDE CART/CHECKOUT PRICE CALCULATIONS 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_cart_price' );

function change_cart_price( $cart_items) {


global $post, $woocommerce, $demomp3, $basicmp3, $basicwav, $premiummp3, $premiumwav, $syncmp3, $syncwav, $demomp3cart, $basicmp3cart, $basicwavcart, $premiummp3cart, $premiumwavcart, $syncmp3cart, $syncwavcart, $admin ,$free, $nonpaid ,$bronze, $silver, $gold, $platinum, $doubleplatinum, $diamond, $freesync, $silversync, $goldsync, $user_id, $wp_user, $pricebasicmp3bronze, $pricebasicmp3silver, $pricebasicmp3gold, $pricebasicmp3platinum, $pricebasicmp3dblplatinum, $pricebasicmp3diamond, $pricebasicwavbronze, $pricebasicwavsilver, $pricebasicwavgold, $pricebasicwavplatinum, $pricebasicwavdblplatinum, $pricebasicwavdiamond, $pricepremiummp3bronze, $pricepremiummp3silver, $pricepremiummp3gold, $pricepremiummp3platinum, $pricepremiummp3dblplatinum, $pricepremiummp3diamond, $pricepremiumwavbronze, $pricepremiumwavsilver, $pricepremiumwavgold, $pricepremiumwavplatinum, $pricepremiumwavdblplatinum, $pricepremiumwavdiamond, $freedemo, $pricedemomp3bronze, $pricedemomp3silver, $pricedemomp3gold, $pricedemomp3platinum, $pricedemomp3dblplatinum, $pricedemomp3diamond, $pricesyncmp3freesync, $pricesyncmp3silversync, $pricesyncmp3goldsync, $pricesyncwavfreesync, $pricesyncwavsilversync, $pricesyncwavgoldsync, $pricedemofreesync, $pricedemosilversync, $pricedemogoldsync, $categories, $category, $getcat;



// Loop through cart items
foreach ($cart_items->cart_contents as $key => $item) {
  $product_name = $item['name'];
  $product_id = $item['product_id'];
  $product_qty = $item['qty'];
  $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
  $price = $item['data']->price;



    //find attributes
            $option1 = 'pa_license-options';
            $option2 = 'pa_delivery-format';
            $getmeta1 = get_post_meta($product_variation_id , 'attribute_'.$option1, true);
            $getmeta2 = get_post_meta($product_variation_id , 'attribute_'.$option2, true);
            $attribute1 = get_term_by('slug', $getmeta1, $option1);
            $attribute2 = get_term_by('slug', $getmeta2, $option2);
            $license = $attribute1->name;
            $format = $attribute2->name;



    if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Demo License" ){
            $democart = $item['data']->price;

            if ( $free || $freesync ) { 
                $item['data']->price = $pricedemofree;
            }
            else if ( $bronze || $silver || $gold || $platinum || $doubleplatinum || $diamond || $silversync || $goldsync  ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $freedemo;
            }   

    }
    if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Basic License" ){
            $basicmp3cart = $item['data']->price;

            if ( $free ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicmp3free;
            }
            if ( $bronze) { 
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicmp3bronze;
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicmp3silver;            
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicmp3gold;
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicmp3platinum;
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicmp3dblplatinum;
            }
            else if ( $diamond ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicmp3diamond;
            }
            else if ( $silversync  ) {  
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $goldsync  ) {
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }

    }
    if ($format === "WAV" && $license === "Basic License" ){
            $basicwavcart = $item['data']->price;

            if ( $free ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicwavfree;
            }
            else if ( $bronze) {    
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicwavbronze;
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicwavsilver;            
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicwavgold;
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicwavplatinum;
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicwavdblplatinum;
            }
            else if ( $diamond ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricebasicwavdiamond;
            }
            else if ( $silversync  ) {  
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $goldsync  ) {
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }

    }
    if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Premium License" ){
            $premiummp3cart = $item['data']->price;

            if ( $free ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiummp3free;
            }
            else if ( $bronze) {    
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiummp3bronze;
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiummp3silver;          
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiummp3gold;
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiummp3platinum;
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiummp3dblplatinum;
            }
            else if ( $diamond ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiummp3diamond;
            }
            else if ( $silversync  ) {  
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $goldsync  ) {
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }

    }
    if ($format === "WAV" && $license === "Premium License" ){
            $premiumwavcart = $item['data']->price;

            if ( $free ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiumwavfree;
            }
            else if ( $bronze) {    
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiumwavbronze;
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiumwavsilver;          
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiumwavgold;
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiumwavplatinum;
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiumwavdblplatinum;
            }
            else if ( $diamond ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricepremiumwavdiamond;
            }
            else if ( $silversync  ) {  
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $goldsync  ) {
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }

    }
    if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Sync License" ){
            $syncmp3cart = $item['data']->price;

            if ( $free ) {  
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            if ( $bronze) { 
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $item['data']->price = '';          
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $diamond ) {  
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $silversync  ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricesyncmp3silversync;
            }
            else if ( $goldsync  ) {
                $item['data']->price = $pricesyncmp3goldsyncsync;
            }

    }   
    if ($format === "WAV" && $license === "Sync License" ){
            $syncwavcart = $item['data']->price;
            if ( $free ) {  
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            if ( $bronze) { 
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $item['data']->price = '';          
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $diamond ) {  
                $item['data']->price = '';
            }
            else if ( $silversync  ) {  
                $item['data']->price = $pricesyncwavsilversync;
            }
            else if ( $goldsync  ) {
                $item['data']->price = $pricesyncwavgoldsyncsync;
            }           
    }
}   
}   



//OVERRIDE PRODUCT PRICES   
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','change_price', 10, 2);
function change_price($price, $productd){





global $post, $woocommerce, $demomp3, $basicmp3, $basicwav, $premiummp3, $premiumwav, $syncmp3, $syncwav, $demomp3cart, $basicmp3cart, $basicwavcart, $premiummp3cart, $premiumwavcart, $syncmp3cart, $syncwavcart, $admin ,$free, $free ,$bronze, $silver, $gold, $platinum, $doubleplatinum, $diamond, $freesync, $silversync, $goldsync, $user_id, $wp_user, $pricebasicmp3bronze, $pricebasicmp3silver, $pricebasicmp3gold, $pricebasicmp3platinum, $pricebasicmp3dblplatinum, $pricebasicmp3diamond, $pricebasicwavbronze, $pricebasicwavsilver, $pricebasicwavgold, $pricebasicwavplatinum, $pricebasicwavdblplatinum, $pricebasicwavdiamond, $pricepremiummp3bronze, $pricepremiummp3silver, $pricepremiummp3gold, $pricepremiummp3platinum, $pricepremiummp3dblplatinum, $pricepremiummp3diamond, $pricepremiumwavbronze, $pricepremiumwavsilver, $pricepremiumwavgold, $pricepremiumwavplatinum, $pricepremiumwavdblplatinum, $pricepremiumwavdiamond, $freedemo, $pricedemomp3bronze, $pricedemomp3silver, $pricedemomp3gold, $pricedemomp3platinum, $pricedemomp3dblplatinum, $pricedemomp3diamond, $pricesyncmp3freesync, $pricesyncmp3silversync, $pricesyncmp3goldsync, $pricesyncwavfreesync, $pricesyncwavsilversync, $pricesyncwavgoldsync, $pricedemofreesync, $pricedemosilversync, $pricedemogoldsync, $categories, $category, $getcat;


$post_id = $variation->ID;

$args = array(
             'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
             'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
             'numberposts'   => -1,
             'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
             'order'         => 'asc',
             'post_parent'   => $post->ID
         );
         $variations = get_posts( $args ); 

//declare variables for later use        





foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {

            $variation_id           = absint( $variation->ID );
            $variable_id = $this['variation_id'];
            $variation_post_status  = esc_attr( $variation->post_status );
            $variation_data         = get_post_meta( $variation_id );
            $variation_data['variation_post_id'] = $variation_id;



            //find attributes
            $option1 = 'pa_license-options';
            $option2 = 'pa_delivery-format';
            $getmeta1 = get_post_meta($variation_id , 'attribute_'.$option1, true);
            $getmeta2 = get_post_meta($variation_id , 'attribute_'.$option2, true);
            $attribute1 = get_term_by('slug', $getmeta1, $option1);
            $attribute2 = get_term_by('slug', $getmeta2, $option2);
            $license = $attribute1->name;
            $format = $attribute2->name;


            //get the prices of each variation by the attribute combinations they have              
            if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Demo License" ){

                //retrieve variation price and assign it to the previously created variable
                $demomp3 = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

            }   
            if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Basic License" ){
                $basicmp3 = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

            }
            if ($format === "WAV" && $license === "Basic License" ){
                $basicwav = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

            }   
            if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Premium License" ){
                $premiummp3 = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

            }
            if ($format === "WAV" && $license === "Premium License" ){
                $premiumwav = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

            }   
            if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Sync License" ){
                $syncmp3 = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

            }   
            if ($format === "WAV" && $license === "Sync License" ){
                $syncwav = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

            }   
}

$getcat = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $getcat as $category ) $categories[] = $category->slug;



    //Simple product doesn't need to be modified
    if($productd->product_type == 'simple'){


        return $price;

    }
    //adjust prices of variable products

    if (  $productd->product_type == 'variation' || $productd->product_type == 'variable' ) {
        if ( in_array( 'licensing', $categories ) ){
        $regprice = get_post_meta( $productd->variation_id, '_regular_price',true);
        //target the current variation by matching its price to the one stored in the variable
        if ($regprice == $demomp3) {

                //apply price adjustment and return the new value
            if ( $free || $freesync || $bronze ) {  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $silver || $gold || $platinum || $doubleplatinum || $diamond || $silversync || $goldsync  ) { 
                $freedemo = $price - $price;    
                $price = $freedemo;
            }       
            return $price;
        }
        else if ($regprice == $basicmp3) {
            if ( $free ) {                  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $bronze ) {                       
                $price = $pricebasicmp3bronze;
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $price = $pricebasicmp3silver;
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $price = $pricebasicmp3gold;                    
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $price = $pricebasicmp3platinum; 
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $price = $pricebasicmp3dblplatinum;                 
            }
            else if ( $diamond  ) { 
                $price = $pricebasicmp3diamond;  
            }
            return $price;
        }
        else if ($regprice == $basicwav) {
            if ( $free ) {                  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $bronze ) {                       
                $price = $pricebasicwavbronze;
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $price = $pricebasicwavsilver;
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $price = $pricebasicwavgold;                    
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $price = $pricebasicwavplatinum; 
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $price = $pricebasicwavdblplatinum;                 
            }
            else if ( $diamond  ) { 
                $price = $pricebasicwavdiamond;  
            }
            return $price;
        }
        else if ($regprice == $premiummp3) {
            if ( $free ) {                  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $bronze ) {                       
                $price = $pricepremiummp3bronze;
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $price = $pricepremiummp3silver;
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $price = $pricepremiummp3gold;                      
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $price = $pricepremiummp3platinum; 
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $price = $pricepremiummp3dblplatinum;                   
            }
            else if ( $diamond  ) { 
                $price = $pricepremiummp3diamond;  
            }
            return $price;
        }
        else if ($regprice == $premiumwav) {
            if ( $free ) {                  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $bronze ) {                       
                $price = $pricepremiumwavbronze;
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $price = $pricepremiumwavsilver;
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $price = $pricepremiumwavgold;                      
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $price = $pricepremiumwavplatinum; 
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $price = $pricepremiumwavdblplatinum;                   
            }
            else if ( $diamond  ) { 
                $price = $pricepremiumwavdiamond;  
            }
            return $price;
        }
        else if ($regprice == $syncmp3) {
            if ( $freesync ) {  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $silversync ) {   
                $price = $pricesyncmp3sliver;  
            }
            else if ( $goldsync ) { 
                $price = $pricesyncmp3gold;  
            }
            else if ( $free ) { 
                $price = '';   
            }
            else if ( $bronze) {            
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $diamond  ) { 
                $price = '';
            }               
            return $price;
        }
        else if ($regprice == $syncwav) {
            if ( $freesync ) {  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $silversync ) {   
                $price = $pricesyncwavsliversync;  
            }
            else if ( $goldsync ) { 
                $price = $pricesyncwavgoldsync;  
            }   
            else if ( $free ) { 
                $price = '';   
            }
            else if ( $bronze) {    

                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $diamond  ) { 
                $price = '';
            }               
            return $price;
        }
        else{           
             return $price;
        }   
    }
    else{
        return $price;
        }
}   

}


//OVERRIDE PRODUCT PRICE HTML DISPLAY   
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'change_display_price', 10, 2);

function change_display_price( $price, $product ) {

 global $demomp3, $basicmp3, $basicwav, $premiummp3, $premiumwav, $syncmp3, $syncwav, $admin ,$free, $free ,$bronze, $silver, $gold, $platinum, $doubleplatinum, $diamond, $freesync, $silversync, $goldsync, $user_id, $wp_user, $pricebasicmp3bronze, $pricebasicmp3silver, $pricebasicmp3gold, $pricebasicmp3platinum, $pricebasicmp3dblplatinum, $pricebasicmp3diamond, $pricebasicwavbronze, $pricebasicwavsilver, $pricebasicwavgold, $pricebasicwavplatinum, $pricebasicwavdblplatinum, $pricebasicwavdiamond, $pricepremiummp3bronze, $pricepremiummp3silver, $pricepremiummp3gold, $pricepremiummp3platinum, $pricepremiummp3dblplatinum, $pricepremiummp3diamond, $pricepremiumwavbronze, $pricepremiumwavsilver, $pricepremiumwavgold, $pricepremiumwavplatinum, $pricepremiumwavdblplatinum, $pricepremiumwavdiamond, $freedemo, $pricedemomp3bronze, $pricedemomp3silver, $pricedemomp3gold, $pricedemomp3platinum, $pricedemomp3dblplatinum, $pricedemomp3diamond, $pricesyncmp3freesync, $pricesyncmp3silversync, $pricesyncmp3goldsync, $pricesyncwavfreesync, $pricesyncwavsilversync, $pricesyncwavgoldsync, $pricedemofreesync, $pricedemosilversync, $pricedemogoldsync, $categories, $category, $getcat, $showmessage;



        $originalprice = '<del style="display: block; line-height: 100%;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>' . $basicmp3 . '</span>-<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>' . $premiumwav . '</span></del>';

        $originalpricesync = '<del style="display: block; line-height: 100%;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>' . $syncmp3 . '</span>-<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>' . $syncwav . '</span></del>';


            if ( $bronze) { 
                $yourprice = '<span class="yourprice bronzetext">Bronze Price: </span>';
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $yourprice = '<span class="yourprice silvertext">Silver Price: </span>';
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $yourprice = '<span class="yourprice goldtext">Gold Price: </span>';
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $yourprice = '<span class="yourprice platinumtext">Platinum Price: </span>';
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $yourprice = '<span class="yourprice dblplatinumtext">Double Platinum Price: </span>';
            }
            else if ( $diamond ) {  
                $yourprice = '<span class="yourprice diamondtext">Diamond Price: </span>';
            }
            else if ( $silversync  ) {  
                $yourprice = '<span class="yourprice diamondtext">Silver Price: </span>';
            }
            else if ( $goldsync  ) {    
                $yourprice = '<span class="yourprice diamondtext">Gold Price: </span>';
            }

        $memberpriceopen = $yourprice . '<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>';
        $memberpricemid = '</span>-<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>';
        $memberpriceclose = '</span></ins>';


    if($product->product_type == 'simple'){


        return $price;

    }
    //adjust prices of variable products    
    if (  $product->product_type == 'variation' || $product->product_type == 'variable' ) {
        if (  in_array( 'licensing', $categories ) ){

            if ( $free ) {  

                return $price;
            }
            else if ( $bronze ) {                   

                $pricelow = $pricebasicmp3bronze;
                $pricehigh = $pricepremiumwavbronze;

                $price = $originalprice . $memberpriceopen . $pricelow . $memberpricemid . $pricehigh . $memberpriceclose;
                return $price;  
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $pricelow = $pricebasicmp3silver;
                $pricehigh = $pricepremiumwavsilver;

                $price = $originalprice . $memberpriceopen . $pricelow . $memberpricemid . $pricehigh . $memberpriceclose;
                return $price;  
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $pricelow = $pricebasicmp3gold;
                $pricehigh = $pricepremiumwavgold;

                $price = $originalprice . $memberpriceopen . $pricelow . $memberpricemid . $pricehigh . $memberpriceclose;
                return $price;                  
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $pricelow = $pricebasicmp3platinum;
                $pricehigh = $pricepremiumwavplatinum;

                $price = $originalprice . $memberpriceopen . $pricelow . $memberpricemid . $pricehigh . $memberpriceclose;
                return $price;  
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {
                $pricelow = $pricebasicmp3dblplatinum;
                $pricehigh = $pricepremiumwavdblplatinum;

                $price = $originalprice . $memberpriceopen . $pricelow . $memberpricemid . $pricehigh . $memberpriceclose;
                return $price;  
            }
            else if ( $diamond  ) { 
                $pricelow = $pricebasicmp3diamond;
                $pricehigh = $pricepremiumwavdiamond;

                $price = $originalprice . $memberpriceopen . $pricelow . $memberpricemid . $pricehigh . $memberpriceclose;
                return $price;  
            }
            else if ( $freesync ) { 
                $pricelow = $pricesyncmp3silversync;
                $pricehigh = $pricesyncwavsilversync;

                $price = $originalprice . $memberpriceopen . $pricelow . $memberpricemid . $pricehigh . $memberpriceclose;
                return $price;  
            }
            else if ( $silversync ) {
                $pricelow = $pricesyncmp3silversync;
                $pricehigh = $pricesyncwavsilversync;

                $price = $originalprice . $memberpriceopen . $pricelow . $memberpricemid . $pricehigh . $memberpriceclose;
                return $price;  
            }
            else if ( $goldsync ) { 
                $pricelow = $pricesyncmp3goldsync;
                $pricehigh = $pricesyncwavgoldsync;

                $price = $originalprice . $memberpriceopen . $pricelow . $memberpricemid . $pricehigh . $memberpriceclose;
                return $price;  
            }
            else{
                return $price;
            }
        }
        else{
            return $price;
        }

    }   
}
```

I can't replicate live results because they require a membership on my website. So I took a screenshot to show what the above code produces.

[image: code results]

Comment: I believe I've already sorted out most of the sites other issues, from console errors, to caching, to image optimization, to selective plugin loading by page, to deferring scripts, so I'm pretty sure I've got those bases covered. While loading still isn't quite instantaneous, the biggest speed difference by FAR happens when I comment out the custom script in question. It probably quadruples load time. I was hesitant to post the entire thing bc SO seems to discourage it, but I went ahead and updated the original post w more info

Comment: Ok thanks I will have a closer look to this and let you know if I have something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I've figured out a solution. I simplified the function that controlled the product prices and things have sped up fairly significantly

```
//OVERRIDE PRODUCT PRICES   
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','change_price', 10, 2);
function change_price($price, $product){


global $post, $woocommerce, $demomp3, $basicmp3, $basicwav, $premiummp3, $premiumwav, $syncmp3, $syncwav, $demomp3cart, $basicmp3cart, $basicwavcart, $premiummp3cart, $premiumwavcart, $syncmp3cart, $syncwavcart, $admin ,$free, $free ,$bronze, $silver, $gold, $platinum, $doubleplatinum, $diamond, $freesync, $silversync, $goldsync, $user_id, $wp_user, $pricebasicmp3bronze, $pricebasicmp3silver, $pricebasicmp3gold, $pricebasicmp3platinum, $pricebasicmp3dblplatinum, $pricebasicmp3diamond, $pricebasicwavbronze, $pricebasicwavsilver, $pricebasicwavgold, $pricebasicwavplatinum, $pricebasicwavdblplatinum, $pricebasicwavdiamond, $pricepremiummp3bronze, $pricepremiummp3silver, $pricepremiummp3gold, $pricepremiummp3platinum, $pricepremiummp3dblplatinum, $pricepremiummp3diamond, $pricepremiumwavbronze, $pricepremiumwavsilver, $pricepremiumwavgold, $pricepremiumwavplatinum, $pricepremiumwavdblplatinum, $pricepremiumwavdiamond, $freedemo, $pricedemomp3bronze, $pricedemomp3silver, $pricedemomp3gold, $pricedemomp3platinum, $pricedemomp3dblplatinum, $pricedemomp3diamond, $pricesyncmp3freesync, $pricesyncmp3silversync, $pricesyncmp3goldsync, $pricesyncwavfreesync, $pricesyncwavsilversync, $pricesyncwavgoldsync, $pricedemofreesync, $pricedemosilversync, $pricedemogoldsync;



            //find attributes
            $option1 = 'pa_license-options';
            $option2 = 'pa_delivery-format';
            $getmeta1 = get_post_meta($product->variation_id , 'attribute_'.$option1, true);
            $getmeta2 = get_post_meta($product->variation_id , 'attribute_'.$option2, true);
            $attribute1 = get_term_by('slug', $getmeta1, $option1);
            $attribute2 = get_term_by('slug', $getmeta2, $option2);
            $license = $attribute1->name;
            $format = $attribute2->name;




    //Simple product doesn't need to be modified
    if($product->product_type == 'simple'){


        return $price;

    }
    //adjust prices of variable products

    if (  $product->product_type == 'variation' || $product->product_type == 'variable' ) {

        //target the current variation by matching its price to the one stored in the variable
        if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Demo License" ){

                //apply price adjustment and return the new value
            if ( $free || $freesync || $bronze ) {  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $silver || $gold || $platinum || $doubleplatinum || $diamond || $silversync || $goldsync  ) { 
                $freedemo = $price - $price;    
                $price = $freedemo;
            }       
            return $price;
        }
        else if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Basic License" ){

            if ( $free ) {                  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $bronze ) {                       
                $price = $pricebasicmp3bronze;
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $price = $pricebasicmp3silver;
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $price = $pricebasicmp3gold;                    
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $price = $pricebasicmp3platinum; 
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $price = $pricebasicmp3dblplatinum;                 
            }
            else if ( $diamond  ) { 
                $price = $pricebasicmp3diamond;  
            }
            return $price;
        }
        else if ($format === "WAV" && $license === "Basic License" ){

            if ( $free ) {                  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $bronze ) {                       
                $price = $pricebasicwavbronze;
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $price = $pricebasicwavsilver;
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $price = $pricebasicwavgold;                    
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $price = $pricebasicwavplatinum; 
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $price = $pricebasicwavdblplatinum;                 
            }
            else if ( $diamond  ) { 
                $price = $pricebasicwavdiamond;  
            }
            return $price;
        }
        else if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Premium License" ){

            if ( $free ) {                  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $bronze ) {                       
                $price = $pricepremiummp3bronze;
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $price = $pricepremiummp3silver;
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $price = $pricepremiummp3gold;                      
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $price = $pricepremiummp3platinum; 
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $price = $pricepremiummp3dblplatinum;                   
            }
            else if ( $diamond  ) { 
                $price = $pricepremiummp3diamond;  
            }
            return $price;
        }
        else if ($format === "WAV" && $license === "Premium License" ){

            if ( $free ) {                  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $bronze ) {                       
                $price = $pricepremiumwavbronze;
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $price = $pricepremiumwavsilver;
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $price = $pricepremiumwavgold;                      
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $price = $pricepremiumwavplatinum; 
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $price = $pricepremiumwavdblplatinum;                   
            }
            else if ( $diamond  ) { 
                $price = $pricepremiumwavdiamond;  
            }
            return $price;
        }
        else if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Sync License" ){

            if ( $freesync ) {  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $silversync ) {   
                $price = $pricesyncmp3sliver;  
            }
            else if ( $goldsync ) { 
                $price = $pricesyncmp3gold;  
            }
            else if ( $free ) { 
                $price = '';   
            }
            else if ( $bronze) {            
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $diamond  ) { 
                $price = '';
            }               
            return $price;
        }
        else if ($format === "WAV" && $license === "Sync License" ){

            if ( $freesync ) {  
                $price = $price;    
            }
            else if ( $silversync ) {   
                $price = $pricesyncwavsliversync;  
            }
            else if ( $goldsync ) { 
                $price = $pricesyncwavgoldsync;  
            }   
            else if ( $free ) { 
                $price = '';   
            }
            else if ( $bronze) {    

                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $silver  ) {  
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $gold ) { 
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $platinum ) { 
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $doubleplatinum ) {   
                $price = '';
            }
            else if ( $diamond  ) { 
                $price = '';
            }               
            return $price;
        }
        else{           
             return $price;
        }   
    }   
}
```